# Syntax error for unexpected '$_SESSION'

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a posting app but found

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) on line 5

Here is the part of code which give Parse error on line 5:

```html
<?php

require "init.php"

$_SESSION["post"] = $_POST["data"];
$_SESSION["privacy"] = $_POST["privacy"];


//transfering to linkedin for authorization
header("location:",
"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=".CLIENTID."&redirect_uri=".REDIRECTURI."&state=".CSRF."&scope=".SCOPES);


?>
```

Kindly have a look on it and guide me what mistake I did.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the ';' in line 3

```
<?php

require "init.php";
//                ^ notice this is missed in your code
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing my little but most important mistake! Its works now. :)

Comment: feel free to remove the question as it is a small typo error :)

Comment: Thanks hassan! Can I share some other pages to you to check what i have missed by using [codeshare.io](http://codeshare.io)

Comment: I will be glad to help

Comment: thanks for the reply. i placed my code here [callback.php](https://codeshare.io/5DPrkr). it shows syntax error on line 42. Kindly have a look on it and let me know what mistake, i am doing. Thanks

Comment: let me know if you get access to the code and trying to find mistake?

Comment: $post=>updateUrl needs to be $post->updateUrl , checkout the arrow meaning in php oop

Comment: Thanks for the help, I update '=>' to '->' on the whole page and error has been removed. But doing this changes the whole code do nothing.

Comment: Can you share your email address so i'll send you whole source code. Why is it not working. or is there alternative method to show you all of pages? Thanks

Comment: you can DM me in twitter.

Comment: I am sorry i did not find you on twitter.

Comment: you will got it in my SO profile

Comment: Thank you very much but i have solved the issue. now I am facing another problem of connecting same page with the database. kindly have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088484/linkedin-login-database-connection) and try to solve it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start();` at the start of your code

```
<?php
session_start();
require "init.php"

$_SESSION["post"] = $_POST["data"];
$_SESSION["privacy"] = $_POST["privacy"];


//transfering to linkedin for authorization
header("location:",
"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=".CLIENTID."&redirect_uri=".REDIRECTURI."&state=".CSRF."&scope=".SCOPES);


?>
```

Comment: I also tried it but same error.