# LinkedIn Login & Database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to connect my Linkedin Login page to the database for getting user information. But whatever I did is just authorized to login a user and database is not receiving any information. Here is my index.php

```html
<?php 
require_once "init.php";
require_once "includes/db.php";

if(isset($_GET['code'])) // get code after authorization
{
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'; 
    $param = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_GET['code'].'&redirect_uri='.$config['callback_url'].'&client_id='.$config['Client_ID'].'&client_secret='.$config['Client_Secret'];
    $return = (json_decode(post_curl($url,$param),true)); // Request for access token
    if($return['error']) // if invalid output error
    {
       $content = 'Some error occured<br><br>'.$return['error_description'].'<br><br>Please Try again.';
    }
    else // token received successfully
    {
       $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,email-address)?format=json&oauth2_access_token='.$return['access_token'];
       $User = json_decode(post_curl($url)); // Request user information on received token
       
      // Insert Data in Database
       $query = "INSERT INTO `linkedti_scheduler`.`users` 
       (`userid`, 
       `firstName`, 
       `lastName`, 
       `emailAddress`, 
       `position`, 
       `location`, 
       `profileURL`, 
       `pictureUrls`, 
       `headline`)
 
       VALUES
 
       ('$id', 
       '$firstName', 
       '$lastName', 
       '$emailAddress', 
       '$position', 
       '$location', 
       '$profileURL', 
       '$pictureUrls', 
       '$headline')";
       mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    }
}
 
?>
 
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>****</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body class="bg">
    
<div align="center" class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" align="middle"/>
</div>


<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" id="button">
                <a href="<?php echo "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=". CLIENTID . "&redirect_uri=".REDIRECTURI."&state=". CSRF."&scope=".SCOPES ; ?>" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-primary btn-block" style="border-radius: 0px;">Login with LinkedIn</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my db.php

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); // Database server
define('DB_USERNAME', '******'); // Database Username
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******'); // Database Password
define('DB_DATABASE', '*******'); // Database Name
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE); // connecting with database
?>
```

Kindly have a look on it and let me know If i missed any part of code or anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will also fix any pesky quoting issues you might have.** Also be sure to check for [mysqli_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) if it's not working like you think it should.

Comment: Just where are your variables coming from? The `$id`, `$firstname`, etc. They're never created.

Comment: @aynber I am sorry I did not get your point. here is my [callback.php](https://codeshare.io/5DPrkr) which is called to get user information. Kindly have a look on it. if this is what you are asking.

Comment: You ask for the data from LinkedIn, and store the results in `$User` (`$User = json_decode(post_curl($url));)`. But you don't do anything with `$User`. Instead, in your insert, you use `$id`, `$firstname`, etch, but they have never been defined. You probably need something like `$User->id`, `$User->firstname`, and so on.

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply. here is the [landing.php](https://codeshare.io/5PpzdP) where i have called user information. My all of pages are working properly. They get authorized access from the linkdin and display user result on the page. but my problem is my database not showing that information.

Comment: if you want to check all of my pages let me know i'll share it with you to check what i have missed. Or you can please kindly share what syntax i have to insert.

Comment: @aynber are you looking for finding solution. Kindly guide me please , what mistake i had done.

Comment: Sorry, your code is a bit convoluted for me to look into, especially when I'm working on my own code. Try echoing your query before you insert it, and check for errors.